# Add HIVE link server in SQL after set an ODBC hortonworks

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm using a couple of Hortonworks services to store huge data, the most common service I use is Hive. the thing is that know I need to analyze from SQL Server 2014. I went thru the documentation and I've already successfully added a new ODBC for my HDP clusted. (HDP 2.6)

[image]

Following a couple of tutorials ([example1](https://www.oraylis.de/blog/querying-hadoop-from-sql-server) and [Example2](http://thinknook.com/connecting-sql-server-and-analysis-services-to-hadoop-hive-2013-07-09/) )I've tried to add a new link server. however these codes are not using a kerberos authentication in their queries.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
@server = ‘[32-bit HIVE ODBC]’
, @srvproduct=’HIVE’
, @provider=’MSDASQL’
, @datasrc='[hive-data-source]’
, @provstr=’Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[username];’
```

Please if someone can give me a hand with the last parameter **@provstr** using kerberos configuration, I appreciate.

thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

i created linked server to hadoop with kerberos only like

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'HADOOP_QA', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'hadoop_qa'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'HADOOP_QA',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
GO
```